# Logical error while implementing flag condition

Tags: c#

I have an event handler in a class SpoServer named HandleSpurtEvents

```
public class SpoServer : DataModelObject, ISpoServer
{
    static private void HandleSpurtEvents(SPD.SPD_eventType type, SPD.SPD_event this_event, object passback)
    {
        if (this_event.variableData[0].atr_value == "refresh")
        {
            if (this_event.variableData[1].atr_value == "complete")
            {
                ss.OnInfoEvent(new InfoEventArgs(SpoServer.InfoEventArgs.InfoType.RefreshComplete, null));
            }
            else
            {
                SpoDebug.DebugTraceSevere(func, "Invalid refresh event: " + this_event.variableData[1].atr_value);
            }
        }
    }

    public bool Modify()
    {
    }
}
```

Here the method Modify, which contain some opertaion what my aim is only allow downside
operation in Modify() method if 'RuntimeUp' property and Refresh complete.So what i did is i created flag 'test' after refresh event and checked with alredy created RuntimeUp.But it throwing errors.test boolean variable is not accessble
That will be something like,here is my work

```
public class SpoServer : DataModelObject, ISpoServer
{
    static private void HandleSpurtEvents(SPD.SPD_eventType type, SPD.SPD_event this_event, object passback)
    {
        if (this_event.variableData[0].atr_value == "refresh")
        {
            if (this_event.variableData[1].atr_value == "complete")
            {
                ss.OnInfoEvent(new InfoEventArgs(SpoServer.InfoEventArgs.InfoType.RefreshComplete, null));
                bool test = true;
            }
            else
            {
                SpoDebug.DebugTraceSevere(func, "Invalid refresh event: " + this_event.variableData[1].atr_value);
            }
        }
    }
    public bool Modify()
    {
        if (!RuntimeUp && test) return false;
    }
}
```

Comment: Please take a moment and format your code when posting a question. It can be hard enough to understand unknown code without random indentation.

Comment: I took the liberty of formatting the code appropriately.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`test` is a method variable  (in `HandleSpurtEvents`) - it only makes sense in the context of that method. If you want it to be an object level variable (field), then relocate it:

```
public class SpoServer : DataModelObject, ISpoServer
{
    private bool test;
    ...
}
```

and don't *declare* it in `HandleSpurtEvents` - just *assign* it:

```
test = true; // intead of: bool test = true;
```

Comment: But test is not coming under if (this_event.variableData[0].atr_value == "refresh")
                        {
                            if (this_event.variableData[1].atr_value == "complete")
                            {

Comment: @peter: you can still *assign it* there: `test = true;`. But for `Modify` to be able to use the value, `test` bust be *declared* in a way so that both methods can see it.

Comment: But test is not coming as intellisence after the line  ss.OnInfoEvent(
                                   new InfoEventArgs(SpoServer.InfoEventArgs.InfoType.RefreshComplete, null));

Comment: @peter - ah, right - it is a `static` event handler - then (since `Modify` is an **instance** method) you'll either need `test` to be `static`, or you'll need an instance of `SpoServer` handy. Or: make the event-handler an instance method rather than `static`